# Show / hide after initial view

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

A user gets directed to a specific page after completing some process.  On this page, there is sensitive information that should be hidden every time after the first view.

How should I go about approaching this problem? Any resources and direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mayby before they are redirected you set a session var like.

Before redirection:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['showDetails']="someSecureString";
header("location: secure.php");
```

Then on the secure page.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['showDetails']) && $_SESSION['showDetails']=="someSecureString"){
     //Show details
     unset ($_SESSION['showDetails']);
}
session_destroy();
```

That should also clear the session var.

Answer (score 0):

use session and unset the session after displaying it (at the end of the page)